# Sendmail log data returns after being deleted

Tags: sendmail

After I completely remove the maillog file from /var/log and reboot the server, the maillog returns with all of the removed data.

Where is the log data saved for sendmail that it can make a new maillog file? I need to completely remove all sendmail log data. How do I do that with CentOS 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sendmail usually logs via `syslogd`.
Possibly you also find logfiles at `/var/spool/mqueue/log`

To delete logfiles you should do a  forced `logrotate` for the file. After waiting some time that the first entries appear in the new logfile you can be sure, the rotated version of the file is not in use anymore and you can delete it.

`logorotate` knows about the log facilites and how to tell them to change to a new logfile gracefully.

I would expect that `logrotate` already rotates the sendmail logs so just waiting for the rotation cycle might be an option.

Details about the configuration of `logrotate` you should find here:

```
/var/lib/logrotate/status    Default state file.
/etc/logrotate.conf          Configuration options.
```